# android how to remove white square shortcut icon from screen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I am using phone with android 4.4.4 version. yesterday suddenly one white square appeared on my screen which looks like shortcuts for keys. It is very much annoying as it appears in all screens, no matter which application I am using. I want to remove/disable it as it permanently.

I searched a lot on internet and I tried to check in settings also but nothing worked out. please help me as this is too irritating. I wonder how google could make such bad feature. Please find the screenshots below.

Problem marked in red circle.

[image]

When I click on square button

[image]

Please note , There is no **mobility** tab under my **"settings>System>accessibility>"**

Answer (score 1):

Since your phone is a Lenovo, as can be seen from your screenshots. The feature is called as **Wide Touch** which adds a floating button on your screen, allowing quick access to system functions.

You can disable Wide Touch in your device's settings. I cannot talk about the exact location of the setting, but for most Lenovo phones, it is in *Settings > Features > Wide Touch*.

The feature can be list item within settings or a separate tab. So, please look carefully through the settings.

Here is the link to Lenovo website explaining the feature for S90 smartphone. Your P70 might have it the same way or with minor changes.
https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht102904

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > System > accessibility > turn off assistant menu under mobility

Hope this will help.